# one of the two labels not being appeared from a cell in tableview swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two labels in my cell in tableview but when I run my app it shows only one label and prints this in console

> `[2142:52393] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f89d80cc000> on <IAuditor.ViewController: 0x7f89d6d13600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

what I have made

[image]

what I get from data now

[image]

what I want

[image]

```
        let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let results = try! context.fetch(request)

    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

        let formNameIs = result.value(forKey: "formName") as? String
        let formDescIs = result.value(forKey: "formDesc") as? String

    cell.titleLabel.text = formNameIs!
    cell.descLabel.text = formDescIs
        print(formNameIs!, formDescIs!)

}
```

Comment: Can you please show screenshot after app run

Comment: have you set correct height for your cell with its delegate method?

Comment: what is your tableviewcell type ?

Comment: Check whether you are returning proper height of your tableViewCell...in `heightForRowAtindexPath` delegate method.

Comment: yes I have proper highet more than the lengths of both labels and

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes I have proper height for cell 80px and labels are 30px both so 20 px are left

Comment: cell height defined programmatically in your code? @iOSDeveloper

Comment: @DharmeshKheni no in xcode

Comment: how can I define it

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
 return 80
 }` this way

Comment: @DharmeshKheni worked! would you answer so I can accept

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Please check below answer.

Comment: thanx Bhai........ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `heightForRowAt` in your code as shown below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 80 
}
```

Comment: thakyou so much Bhai, would you do some extra effort updated question

Comment: Sorry not getting your question. What do want this updated question?

Comment: reload te question and see images what I want, I want to show the all values that are printed in console in row currently only one data is printed in many cells but I want single data for single row

Comment: I think you need to increase width of you labels.

Comment: reload te question and see images what I want, I want to show the all values that are printed in console in row currently only one data is printed in many cells but I want single data for single row – iOS Developer 52 secs

Comment: here is the link I have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854988/get-all-attributes-of-an-entity-to-a-label-in-row-in-tableview-with-core-data-sw

Comment: would you answer this plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881304/alertcontroller-is-being-poped-every-time-in-nested-conditions-swift-ios