# Get all attributes of an entity to a label in row in tableview with core data swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uilabel

I have defined the two attribues Name and description to an entity named `Forms` and I want retrieve the name in first label and desc in 2nd label in a row of a tableview

what I have made

[image]

what I cuurently retrieve

[image]

I want these all values to be printed in every cell instead of sigle cell repeated every time

[image]

```
        let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
let results = try! context.fetch(request)

for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

    let formNameIs = result.value(forKey: "formName") as? String
    let formDescIs = result.value(forKey: "formDesc") as? String

cell.titleLabel.text = formNameIs!
cell.descLabel.text = formDescIs
    print(formNameIs!, formDescIs!)

}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @pbasdf updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have misunderstood how tableViews work.  You do not need to iterate through all the objects; you should locate the correct object for the row (as indicated in the `indexPath` argument), and set the labels using the attribute values from that object.

So, make the `results` array a property of your view controller:

```
var results : [NSManagedObject] = []
```

In `viewDidLoad`, populate your `results` array from CoreData:

```
...
// presumably you have code to define the fetch request
let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
results = try! context.fetch(request)
```

In the tableView's `numberOfRowsInSection` method, return the count of objects in `results`

```
return results.count
```

And in the tableView's `cellForRowAt:` method, locate the correct object from the `results` array, using the `indexPath` argument:

```
let result = results[indexPath.row]
let formNameIs = result.value(forKey: "formName") as? String
let formDescIs = result.value(forKey: "formDesc") as? String
cell.titleLabel.text = formNameIs!
cell.descLabel.text = formDescIs
print(formNameIs!, formDescIs!)
```

Comment: would you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881304/alertcontroller-is-being-poped-every-time-in-nested-conditions-swift-ios