# AlertController is being popped every time in nested conditions swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nested-loops, nested-if

I have defined an alertcontroller when username or password is not correct the alert should pop, and it is working fine. but when the username & password is matched despite matching it pops up everytime when log in. I think I have not defined nested condition in a right way? help me to sort the multiple nested condition.

**Code for Login**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var usernameGlobal : String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passText: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      //  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "" + emailText.text!)


    do {

    let results = try! context.fetch(request)

        if(results.count > 0){

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
            {


                if  emailText.text == result.value(forKey: "username") as? String && passText.text == result.value(forKey: "password") as? String {
                    print(emailText.text!, passText.text!)
                    usernameGlobal = self.emailText.text!
                    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
                    let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
                    let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
                    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)

                }

                else {

                       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

            }

            }
        }
    }



@IBAction func signupSegue(_ sender: Any) {

    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
    let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignupViewController") as! SignupViewController
    let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: is your results.count == 1?

Comment: if(results.count > 0){

Comment: there's a chance that your results array contains an object that does not have "username" and "password". thus your else condition will always happen.

Comment: You should declare and maintain one boolean flag as false. Set that flag as true if any username matches and break the loop. after loop check if flag is false then you should show alert for wrong username or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let isMatched = false
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

         do {

            let results = try! context.fetch(request)

            if(results.count > 0){

                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
                {


                    if  emailText.text == result.value(forKey: "username") as? String && passText.text == result.value(forKey: "password") as? String {
                        print(emailText.text!, passText.text!)
                        usernameGlobal = self.emailText.text!
                        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
                        let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
                        let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
                        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
                        isMatched = true
                        break

                    }

                }

                if !isMatched {

                      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                      let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                      alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                      present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                 }

            }
        }
    }
```

Changes:

You add

```
        let isMatched = false
```

You add **break** statement in if condition. So that it breaks the loop once username and password is matched. Then after for loop check if the isMatched is false, then show the result.

Answer (score 0):

if your result contains multiple different element then else block will execute multiple time. thats why alert appeared multiple time . when you found a match then you should return . if no match found then after loop alert will appear for one time .

Use this:

```
       @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

            let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            //  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "" + emailText.text!)


            do {

                let results = try! context.fetch(request)

                if(results.count > 0){

                    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
                    {


                        if  emailText.text == result.value(forKey: "username") as? String && passText.text == result.value(forKey: "password") as? String {
                            print(emailText.text!, passText.text!)
                            usernameGlobal = self.emailText.text!
                            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
                            let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
                            let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
                            revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
                            return

                        }
                    }
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Explain what you have changed so that OP can understand what is wrong with his code.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni ok